# Understanding the rate of infection in SIR models

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, related-rates

I'm having a difficult time understanding the intuition behind the rate that susceptible individuals become infected in SIR-type models.

The infection rate (number of susceptibles infected per time period) is often written as $a c S I$, where $c$ is the probability that susceptibles ($S$) interact with infected individuals ($I$) per infected individual per day, and $a$ is the probability that an interaction results in infection.

However, consider $a = 0.9$ and $c = 0.1$, and a population of $900$ susceptible people and $100$ infected people. Then, the number of people infected per day is $a c S I = 0.9 \cdot 0.1 \cdot 900 \cdot 100 = 8100$, which doesn't make sense (to me) because the number of infected is much larger than the number of susceptible people. I realise that in this case, the probability of contact per infected individual per day ($a$) is unrealistically high, but even if $a$ was smaller, and the populations were bigger, then we could run into problems.

I originally thought that this problem was answered by continuous time models, where the interactions take place in a tiny interval of time, but even discrete-time SIR models include this type of interaction for the infection rate.

Can anyone help me understand why the $a c S I$ formulation makes sense enough for it to be used?

Comment: my memory is hazy but Isn't there normally a 1/N factor?

Comment: In the original formulation, I can't see one? e.g. https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Kermack-McKendrickModel.html

Answer (score 1):

This is the difference between models using population density and such using population counts. What you have in mind is the density equation
$$
\dot s = -acs\imath
$$
where $s=\frac SN$ and $\imath=\frac IN$ are densities. If you insert that you get for the equation of the counts
$$
\dot S = -ac\frac{SI}N.
$$

Comment: Okay, thanks. But doesn't your count model have the wrong dimensions? If $c$ has dimensions 1/(infected*time), your count model has dimensions 1/time?  Many treatments of SIR models have the term written just as $\beta S I$ - isn't there a similar problem that this form could return higher number of susceptibles infected than there are susceptibles in the population? $\beta$ is probability of transmission per infected individual per time unit. Sorry if I'm being thick here

Comment: Only the product $β=ac$ needs to have the dimension $1/time$. For instance, $c$ could be more precisely described as the number of encounters of more that 15min *per day*. $a$ is the probability that a 15min encounter leads to an infection, this is a pure probability without any units.